# parsing image from description tag of rss/Xml feeds windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-8

Any body please tell me how can we get image from description tag.

the description tag is below

```
 <p style="text-align: center;"><img hspace="1" height="312" border="1" align="middle"                              width="300" vspace="3" src="/recipeuserfiles/Katte Pongali-andhra recipes-healthy recipes.PNG" alt="" /></p> <ul> <li>Mix the rice and Green gram dal Cook in pressure cooker and keep it side. </li> <li>Now take a vessel and heat the ghee and add add pepper, cumin seeds, curry leaves and cashew nuts to it. </li> <li>Then add the cokked rice and dal , salt and mix it properly. </li> <li>Delicious pongali is ready to taste. Have it with any of your favorite chutney.</li> </ul>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to extract information from HTML easily. For example :

```cs
var html = @"<p style=""text-align: center;""><img hspace=""1"" height=""312"" border=""1"" align=""middle""                              width=""300"" vspace=""3"" src=""/recipeuserfiles/Katte Pongali-andhra recipes-healthy recipes.PNG"" alt="""" /></p> <ul> <li>Mix the rice and Green gram dal Cook in pressure cooker and keep it side. </li> <li>Now take a vessel and heat the ghee and add add pepper, cumin seeds, curry leaves and cashew nuts to it. </li> <li>Then add the cokked rice and dal , salt and mix it properly. </li> <li>Delicious pongali is ready to taste. Have it with any of your favorite chutney.</li> </ul>";
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
var src = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//img").GetAttributeValue("src", "");

//this will print /recipeuserfiles/Katte Pongali-andhra recipes-healthy recipes.PNG
Console.WriteLine(src);
```

There are many articles/tutorials on net covering how to install HAP and getting started with it, you can search for it anytime.

Comment: I have written the same code.I was not getting any errors even though image was not displayed.I was unable to understand were the problem is.please help me.I was struggling on this from many days.